# CEFSharp Not Loading, and showing invisible area

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am trying to use cefsharp so i downloaded the repository from their website and tried to copy and paste every thing as it is from the windows forms application to my application in order to use the `ChromiumWebBrowser.cs` that comes with it... however when i run my application it only display a white area (sometimes just invisible hole) with no error or anything... have been trying for over 30 hours with no luck although it is running normally at the example project.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to copy any thing, just install Cefsharp from Nugetmanager of Visual studio.
[GetStartfromhere](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 0):

See this related issue for suggestions: [CefSharp WinForms Web Browser Won't Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307444/cefsharp-winforms-web-browser-wont-display)

If that doesn't help a few particular items you should check:

- Work your way from the `CefSharp.MinimalExample` repo which now contains a WinForms example
- Start your project by using the NuGet package (as mentioned in the SO answer above). It takes care of copying all needed Chromium resources
- Make sure your NuGet version is at least 2.7
- Setup your project configuration as *either* `x86` *or* `x64` ... with `AnyCPU` the NuGet magic won't work currently