# CefSharp WinForms Web Browser Won't Display

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a dead simple example trying to get the CEF Browser to append on a Winforms Form. For some reason it won't display.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser test = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com");
        this.Controls.Add(test);
    }
}
```

Below is the VS Solution I am using. I added the package via [Nuget](http://andrewherrick.com/spike/cef.zip)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code above is a bit *too* dead simple :)

It's missing a call to `Cef.Initialize()`

See the `Main()` method of the `CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms` [example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/33ab4ef53824b67b8934814755da9d28edbab983/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs) for a working example and further details on how to use CefSharp.

You also need to give the control a `DockStyle.Fill`, like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var test = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com")
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    };
    this.Controls.Add(test);
}
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. I was missing initialize. Thank you :)