# My Chromium browser object won't display in Winform

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I was using the .Net WebBrowser object but don't like the messy way the compatibility mode works. So I switched to CEFSharp object.

However, the object doesn't display in my form.  I looked at the Example Winform project with CEFSharp but it doesn't seem to display it in a winform but runs it as a separate application which isn't want i want.

I figure I am missing some obvious method or property that must be set initially. In the code below I have what I am using for CEFSharp and you will see two lines commented out which is what I was using for .Net WebBrowser that worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace GoogleSiren
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser myBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://wwww.cnn.com");
        //WebBrowser myBrowser = new WebBrowser();

        //myBrowser.Navigate("http://www.cnn.com");
        myBrowser.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        myBrowser.Size = new Size(500, 300);
        this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307444/cefsharp-winforms-web-browser-wont-display?rq=1 Note: Don't expect CefSharp to be a 1-to-1 drop in for the MS `WebBrowser` API wise.

Comment: Thanks kindly. It is indeed a dupe as I added Cef.Initialize() and it works.  The example I had looked at in the distribution spawned it as a separate application and didn't have that call there.  What I don't understand is why when I searched SO I didn't see this dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was missing Cef.Initialize() call. Once I added that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Size and Location as part of the constructor:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser myBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://wwww.cnn.com") 
{
   Location = new Point(200, 200),
   Size = new Size(500, 300)
};
this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
```